Is a NC sphere a (one point) compactification of a NC plane?
Inspired by this question About noncommutative sphere and inspired by the fact that the classical sphere is the one point compactificatiin of $\mathbb{R}^2$ we ask the question below:


Is the non commutative sphere $A_q$ mentioned in the above linked post a (minimal)unitization of a non commutative deformation $B_q$ of $C_0(\mathbb{R}^2)$?


One may pose this question for any other NC deformation of classical sphere

$C_0(\mathbb{R}^2)$ is generated by two functions $a = \frac{1}{1+x^2+y^2}$ and $b = \frac{x+iy}{1+x^2+y^2}$. They are subject to the relations $a=a^\ast$, $ab=ba$, $ab^\ast=b^\ast a$, $bb^\ast=b^\ast b=a(1-a)$, and it is not hard to verify that $C_0(\mathbb{R}^2)$ is exactly the universal (non-unital) $C^\ast$-algebra generated by $a,b$ subject to those relations. If you introduce a parameter $q$ and deform these relations by $q$, you can get exactly the defining relations of $A_q$ in the linked post, with the only difference being we’re no longer requiring a unit. If we let $B_q$ be the…

… universal (non-unital) $C^\ast$-algebra generated by $a,b$ subject to relations listed in the linked post, it seems we can say $B_q$ is a deformation of $C_0(\mathbb{R}^2)$ in some suitable sense, and indeed $A_q$ is the unitization of $B_q$.

@DavidGao thank you. what can be said about the generalization? The last part of the question? Is there a perturbation $A_q$ of a classical space X which is a compactification of a classical Y such that no perturbation of $C_0(Y)$ can be found whose unitization is $A_q$?

@DavidGao I guess you mean$a-a^2$ not $a(1-a)$? BTW do relations you mentioned work and generate the algebra?

I remember that descriptiin of classical and NC torus is inspir3d by Fourier series periodic functions in two variabkes. So how do you describe NC non compact plane?

@DavidGao  Any way it  would be interesting to have a perturbation of  a  compact space  which is  not minimal  compactification of any non compact perturbation. can one imagin a possible example?

I’m not sure about any of these. I’d suggest you read the literature on various quantum algebras to find out. Again, I’m not an expert in these topics. I’m simply dealing with the definition of quantum spheres as laid before me. I’m not even sure how would you rigorously define “non-commutative deformation” or “perturbation” of classical functional algebras in full generality.

I wrote $a(1-a)$ for the sake of making the analogies to the relations defining $A_q$ clear. It’s not really an issue as you can always pass to the unitization and work there. As long as it ends up landing in the original algebra, it doesn’t matter.

What did you mean by “do relations you mentioned work and generate the algebra”? I already said the universal algebra subject to those relations is $C_0(\mathbb{R}^2)$, didn’t I?

@DavidGao  Yes you  did. But  my question is that  why  these relations  generate $C_0(R^2)$? the  term  $\frac{1}{x^2+y^2+1}$ you idicated to remind of  "Poincare  compactification"  which is  NOT a 1 point  compactification. In this  case the  equator  of  sphere play  the role of  infinity(Not  a unique point $\infty$)

@DavidGao  So  Please  write a  rigorous proof that they  generate  $C_0(R^2)$

Note that $C_0(R^2)$  correspond to  1 point  compactification but the  fraction you  used  compactify the infinity to  ${(x,y,o)\in S^2$$

I’m not sure what you’re talking about. $a, b$ are functions on $\mathbb{R}^2$, not coordinate transform maps, and they both send the point at infinity to $0$, as is required for them to be even in $C_0(\mathbb{R}^2)$, not to the equator. I’ll write a rigorous proof later. I don’t have time at the moment, but it’s easier to work with the one-point compactification and first show its one-point compactification is the sphere.

@DavidGao  Thank  you  for  your  attention to my question. Ok we can talk later  if  you  have no time  just  now. Since  last  night I realy wonder if there  would be  a unital perturbation whose  realization as  minimal unitization of a non unital perturbation would produce some interesting stories. We possibly  talk later

@DavidGao  I  mean: Pick  a  classic   non  compact  space $Y$ then one point compactify to $X$ then perturbe $X$  to $X_q$ in the  virtual word which commutativity is forbidden then try to realize  $X_q$ as a minimal unitization. This is my  concern.

I’ve added a proof that those relations generate $C_0(\mathbb{R}^2)$ as an answer. (Tangentially, the proof also shows that the universal unital algebra subject to those relations is indeed the algebra of the sphere.) As for your later follow-up comment, again, I’m not an expert in these quantum deformations. If you have something more specific in mind (namely, you can’t just say perturbing something, you have to define these deformations in a more rigorous way for me), maybe I can work with it. As of now, the most I can do are all contained in my answers here and to the linked question.

This is really a long comment. We first show that the universal abelian $C^\ast$-algebra $A$ generated by two generators $a,b$ subject to the relations $a = a^\ast$ and $|b|^2 = a(1-a)$ is $C_0(\mathbb{R}^2)$, with $a = \frac{1}{1+x^2+y^2}$ and $b = \frac{x+iy}{1+x^2+y^2}$.
To do this, we consider the unitization $\tilde{A}$ of $A$. By considering the universal property satisfied by $\tilde{A}$, it is clear that it is the universal unital abelian $C^\ast$-algebra $A$ generated by two generators $a,b$ subject to the relations $a = a^\ast$ and $|b|^2 = a(1-a)$. Note that $a(1-a) = |b|^2 \geq 0$, so as $a$ is self-adjoint, by functional calculus, we have $0 \leq a \leq 1$. Then,
$$\|b\|^2 = \||b|^2\| = \|a(1-a)\| \leq \sup_{0 \leq x \leq 1} |x(1-x)| = \frac{1}{4}$$
So $\|b\| \leq \frac{1}{2}$. Let $c = \text{Re}(b)$ and $d = \text{Im}(b)$. Then $c,d$ are both self-adjoint elements of norm at most $\frac{1}{2}$. We renormalize these a bit by defining $u = 2a-1$, $v = 2c$, $w = 2d$. Then $\tilde{A}$ is generated as a unital $C^\ast$-algebra by $u,v,w$. We also have $\sigma(u), \sigma(v), \sigma(w) \subset [-1, 1]$, so by functional calculus, there is a surjective $\ast$-homomorphism:
$$\pi: B := C([-1, 1]^3) \to \tilde{A}, \pi(f \otimes g \otimes h) = f(u)g(v)h(w)$$
Let the three coordinate projections on $[-1, 1]^3$ be denoted by $x,y,z$, respectively. Then $\pi(x) = u$, $\pi(y) = v$, $\pi(z) = w$. As $\tilde{A}$ is a quotient of $B$, $\tilde{A}$ is the algebra of continuous functions on some closed subset $X \subset [-1, 1]^3$. The relation defining $\tilde{A}$ is $|b|^2 = a(1-a)$, which, translated in terms of $u,v,w$, is,
$$(\frac{v}{2})^2 + (\frac{w}{2})^2 = \frac{1+u}{2} \cdot \frac{1-u}{2} \Leftrightarrow u^2 + v^2 + w^2 = 1$$
So $\tilde{A} = B/\langle x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 1 \rangle$. Thus, $\tilde{A} = C(X)$ where,
$$X = \{(x,y,z) \in [-1, 1]^3: x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1\}$$
That is, $\tilde{A} = C(S^2)$. Note that $u,v,w$ corresponds to the three Cartesian coordinate functions $x,y,z$, so,
$$a = \frac{1+u}{2} = \frac{1+x}{2}, b = \frac{v+iw}{2} = \frac{y+iz}{2}$$
Now, $A$ is the (non-unital) $C^\ast$-subalgebra generated by $a$ and $b$. The only point on the unit sphere where both $a$ and $b$ are zero is $(-1,0,0)$, so,
$$A = C_0(S^2 \setminus \{(-1,0,0)\}) \simeq C_0(\mathbb{R}^2)$$
Finally, we show that we may choose $a = \frac{1}{1+x^2+y^2}$ and $b = \frac{x+iy}{1+x^2+y^2}$ in $C_0(\mathbb{R}^2)$. This follows from choosing an appropriate homeomorphism $\phi: \mathbb{R}^2 \to S^2 \setminus \{(-1,0,0)\}$:
$$\phi(x,y) = (\frac{1-x^2-y^2}{1+x^2+y^2}, \frac{2x}{1+x^2+y^2}, \frac{2y}{1+x^2+y^2})$$
It is a homeomorphism as, one may easily verify, it admits a continuous inverse,
$$\phi^{-1}(x,y,z) = (\frac{y}{1+x}, \frac{z}{1+x})$$
Thus, under this identification, $a$, as an element of $C_0(\mathbb{R}^2)$, is,
$$\frac{1+x}{2} \circ \phi = \frac{1}{1+x^2+y^2}$$
And $b$ is,
$$\frac{y+iz}{2} \circ \phi = \frac{x+iy}{1+x^2+y^2}$$
This proves the claim.

Now, as I have observed in comments, the relations defining $A$ may be easily restated as $A$ being the universal $C^\ast$-algebra generated by two generators $a,b$ subject to the relations:
$$a = a^\ast, ab = ba, ab^\ast = b^\ast a, bb^\ast = b^\ast b = a(1-a)$$
If we introduce a parameter $0 < q <1$ and deform these relations, we can then get the relations defining the quantum sphere modulo unitality,
$$a = a^\ast, ab = q^2ba, ab^\ast = q^{-2}b^\ast a, bb^\ast = q^{-2}a(1-a), b^\ast b = a(1-q^2a)$$
We retrieve the relations defining $A$ as $q \to 1$. Let the universal (non-unital) $C^\ast$-algebra generated by $a,b$ subject to the above deformed relations be $B_q$. Then $B_q$ is a deformation of $A = C_0(\mathbb{R}^2)$ and the unitization of $B_q$ is the quantum sphere, $A_q$.
